# How to combine code-coverage from unittests using Cython and conventional C/C++ test frameworks

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, cython

I am using Cython to wrap existing C-Code related to algorithmics, in order to perform unit tests or run simulations using Python. However, I also have conventional unit tests in C/C++ (Catch2) for simple test-cases. I can run lcov on the Catch2 tests in order to get a code-coverage overview.

1. Is it possible to get a code coverage of the part of the C-code that is tested with Python (via the Cython extension)? How?
2. Is it possible to combine the code coverage from the Catch2 tests and the Python/Cython unit tests?